# how to validate a file name at upload in zend framework?

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, file-upload, validation

i an trying to upload a file and i need it to contain only letters, numbers and _

here is my code

```
    $regex = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/i');
    $regex->setMessages(array(
        Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'NOT MATCH - File name can only contain letters, numbers and underscores',
        Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID   => 'INVALID - File name can only contain letters, numbers and underscores',
        Zend_Validate_Regex::ERROROUS  => 'ERROR - File name can only contain letters, numbers and underscores'
    ));

    $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
    $file->setRequired(TRUE)
        ->setDestination($path)
        ->addValidator('Size', FALSE, array('min' => '10kB', 'max' => '100MB'))
        ->addValidator('Extension', FALSE, 'avi,mov,wmv,mpeg,flv,mpg,mp4')
        ->addValidator($regex)
        ->getValidator('Upload')->setMessage('No file selected');
    $file->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $file->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $file->getDecorator('Label')->setTag(NULL);
```

i want this file to pass: `test_test.jpeg`

but not this one: `test test.jpeg`

the issue i am having is that even if the file name is OK the validator still throws the `NOT_MATCH` error

i even allowed `.` in case the file name is the entire file name string

any ideas?

Comment: Well maybe the filename isn't stored as 'test_test.jpg' but as 'c:\fakepath\test_test.jpg'?

Comment: good point, that seems to be the issue, but i still need to validate the file name only. not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(.*/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*?\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]*?$/i
```

Get rid of everything past the "\." if you don't require an extension. Otherwise, this should work for both full path and file-only names